# Reference of cell value from one dataframe in another dataframe - getting NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cell

I am trying to map a particular cell of a bank statement into data frame.  When I locate the value it is reading values perfectly, but when I include it into a dataframe it is coming 'NaN'.  I would like to bring the balance to new dataframe. Thanks for your support.

[image: Query and output for reference.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is ouput is one element `DataFrame`, need scalar. So select by scalars instead range:

```
info['balance'] = data2.iloc[11, 2]
```

For last row is possible use `-1`:

```
info['balance'] = data2.iloc[-1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Will try out the options.